# Output involving increment operator

Tags: c, output

Explain the output
. Program has been compiled on gnu (gcc 4.9.2 compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i=1;
    int arr[]={2,3,4,5};
    int x=(i++<3);

    printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d",i,x,++i[arr],i++[arr],i);
}
```

output :`3  1  6  4  3`

Comment: You have mistakes. That code WON'T compile (even on gcc :-)

Comment: What about this do you not understand? How does it differ from what you expect. Be specific.

Comment: It is undefined behavior. The output could be anything.

Comment: @Amit , Actually, it does compile. But with warnings...

Comment: @CoolGuy `i[arr]` would compile? didn't know that... what would it translate into?

Comment: @Amit See this question: ["With C arrays, why is it the case that `a[5]` == `5[a]` ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

Comment: @WhozCraig, CoolGuy - good to know :-)

Comment: @AyushNigam there is no explanation for the output. Your parameters instigate unsequenced evaluation and modification to `i`. In fact, clang even warns you about it: "Unsequenced modification and access to 'i'". If gcc doesn't consider turning up your warning levels and options.

Comment: int x=(i++<3); is a boolean Operation. so x gets the value 1. 
++i[arr] and i++[arr] is an address, but not the address of the Array, this behaviour is undefined and can let the Programm Crash. I think it should be arr[i++] or arr[++i]

Comment: @Miguel13366 The multiple access to `i` in the same expression is what's undefined behavior. The [obscure ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) of `i` versus `arr` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Lundin: Sure. But I think the address of 'i' is also undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a "side effect". Depending on the underlying architecture, the parameters to printf() are evaluated from left-to-right or from right-to-left (f.e. HPUX).

So you cannot say, what is "THE" result. You can only specify the result on your operating system with your compiling chain.

This behaviour is called [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: First of all,in c arr[i] is equivalent to i[arr] NOW coming to the main point the above question does have a solution and is not machine dependent because it has been asked in many reputed company interviews like Adobe etc.So I would be really glad to know the correct answer

Comment: NOPE: `function(f1(),f2());` depends on the calling strategy (we talk about "C" not about "C++"!), if f1 and f2 have side-effects, the result is different on different architectures.

Comment: the correct answer is: "under C, this is machine dependend behaviour".